# ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert

Tags: brownie, defi, aave

Im building an DEFIAPP (AAVE)V3

1. I do have enough eth
2. function deposit(address asset, uint256 amount, address onBehalfOf, uint16 referralCode) external
3. Added settings:
   gas_limit: "100000000000" in brownie_config.yaml
4. Have WETH
5. All interfaces are compiled
6. No error in  get_weth.py and helful_scripts.py
7. weth_token, pool_addresses_provider are correctly added in the brownie-config

**Here is my aave_borrow.py**

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from scripts.get_weth import get_weth
from brownie import interface, config, network
from web3 import Web3

Amount=Web3.toWei(0.1,"ether")
def main ():
    account=get_account()
    erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
    #get_weth()
    if network.show_active() in ["mainnet-fork"]:
        get_weth()

    pool = get_pool()
    
    approve_ERC20(Amount,pool.address,erc20_address,account)
    #deposit for v1/2 supply for v3 
    print("Depositing ")
    tx=pool.deposit(erc20_address,Amount,account.address,0,{"from":account})
    tx.wait(2)
    print("Deposited")
    

def get_pool():
    #ABI
    #Address
    pool_addresses_provider=interface.IPoolAddressesProvider(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["pool_addresses_provider"]
        
    )
    pool_address=pool_addresses_provider.getPool()
    pool_abi=interface.IPool(pool_address)
    return pool_abi

   
   
   


def approve_ERC20(amount,spender,erc20_address,account):
    print("Approving Token... ")
    erc20=interface.IERC20(erc20_address)
    tx=erc20.approve(spender,amount,{"from":account})
    tx.wait(2)
    print("Approvedddd!!")
    return tx
```

Running the code using  **brownie run scripts/aave_borrow.py --network sepolia**

Error that I had
AaveBrowniePyProject is the active project.

```
Running 'scripts\aave_borrow.py::main'...

Approving Token... 
    tx=pool.deposit(erc20_address,Amount,account.address,0,{"from":account})
  File "C:\Users\Salma, line line, in in
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Salma, line line, in in
    return tx["from"].transfer(
  File "C:\Users\Salma, line line, in in
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\Salma, line line, in in
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
  File "C:\Users\Salma, line line, in in
    raise ValueError(str(exc)) from None
ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.
```

Comment: Please add pool_address.